# SVN: Can you merge a single check-in into another branch?

Tags: svn, merge, checkin

I know that you can merge two branches together, but what about single check-ins?

For example, I've used SourceGear Vault in the past to merge check-ins.  If I modifed several files in my project and checked them all in at once, this was considered a single check-in even though it consisted of multiple files.  If I wanted to merge just these changes into another branch without merging the entire branch that may contain someone else's changes that I *don't* want merged, I could just merge only the files from my check-in.

Can I do this with SVN?

Comment: while at the top of the destination branch checkout: svn merge -c revision_id source_branch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll probably get thumbed down for answering my own question when two people have already provided what are probably legitimate answers, but I found a command-line-free way to do this using TortoiseSVN's Windows Explorer integration. I followed these steps:

- From Windows Explorer, I right-clicked the folder containing the project that's tied to the DESTINATION branch and selected TortoiseSVN > Merge.
- In the dialog box that popped up, I selected "Merge a range of revisions"
- In the next window, I selected the SOURCE repository branch that contains the changes I want merged and clicked `Show log` to get the revision number of the check-in
- I did a test merge to make sure it worked, after which I proceeded with the merge, checked the working copy of my VS 2010 project, and all my code was there!

FWIW, I upvoted the other guys for good measure.

Comment: I just followed these instructions, but I think the first step should say **DESTINATION branch**.  That's what I did, and it worked great.

Comment: @JPhi1618 answer updated to reflect your correction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. See [the manual section on "cherrypicking".](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking)

Comment: -1. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer on how to write good answers